# My dynamic query works for when both parentsku and child sku data is present,but is not working when child is absent but parent sku is present

Tags: sql, sql-server

My dynamic query works for when both parentsku and childsku data is present,but is not working when childsku is absent but parentsku is present.This is the case it is not working ...I want it to handle both the cases...

Here is my input table
[image: Input table]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products


    SET @SQL = 'SELECT 
    a.'+@Parent_SKU+' AS ''Parent SKU''
    ,COUNT('+@Child_SKU+') AS ''ChildSKU_Total''
    ,STUFF((SELECT '','' +'+@Child_SKU+'
               FROM ['+@TableName+'] b 
               WHERE b.'+@Parent_SKU+' = a.'+@Parent_SKU+' 
              FOR XML PATH('''')),1, 1, '''') AS ''ChildSKU''
    INTO ##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products
    FROM ['+@TableName+'] a
    GROUP BY '+@Parent_SKU+'';

    PRINT(@SQL) 
    EXEC(@SQL)
    SELECT *FROM ##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products;
```

Here is the expected result I want:
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT 
a.'+@Parent_SKU+' AS ''Parent SKU''
,sum(case when '+@Child_SKU+' is null or '+@Child_SKU+' = ''  then 0 else 1 end) AS ''ChildSKU_Total''
,STUFF((SELECT '','' +'+@Child_SKU+'
           FROM ['+@TableName+'] b 
           WHERE b.'+@Parent_SKU+' = a.'+@Parent_SKU+' 
                AND b.'+@Child_SKU+' IS NOT NULL 
          FOR XML PATH('''')),1, 1, '''') AS ''ChildSKU''
INTO ##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products
FROM ['+@TableName+'] a
GROUP BY '+@Parent_SKU+'';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate NULL into a string, the result is NULL. This applies for many other SQL operators as well.

So you could try to use ISNULL(@sku, 'null') or something along those lines.

Why must this be constructed dynamically? Dynamic SQL is rarely necessary and can pose a security risk. If I were you I would try to do this using a parameterized query/stored procedure.

Comment: it is a store procedure @Eric but here i only posted the problem part .... thanks

Comment: Do any of those parameters get set from a form or table that accepts user input?

Comment: they get the input from a global temp table

Answer (score 1):

there may be NULL values in the Child_SKU column, add a where condition as below to avoid null values and unnecessary comma.

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT 
a.'+@Parent_SKU+' AS ''Parent SKU''
,COUNT('+@Child_SKU+') AS ''ChildSKU_Total''
,STUFF((SELECT '','' +'+@Child_SKU+'
           FROM ['+@TableName+'] b 
           WHERE b.'+@Parent_SKU+' = a.'+@Parent_SKU+' 
                AND b.'+@Child_SKU+' IS NOT NULL 
          FOR XML PATH('''')),1, 1, '''') AS ''ChildSKU''
INTO ##TEMP_ParentsChild_Products
FROM ['+@TableName+'] a
GROUP BY '+@Parent_SKU+'';
```